# Symfony's autogenerated backend app is not loading any stylesheet

Tags: symfony1, stylesheet, propel, backend, auto-generate

i'm working on a symfony project, but by now that i'm a noob in web developement i'm doing the famous jobeet tutorial.

### My problem is:

When i autogenerate the backend app, i see the plain layout defined in the /apps/backend/templates/layout.php file. This have happened  to me generating other things but this time i have no files to touch and manualy add the style sheets. So

### my question is:

Where are the files i have to modify to apply a *.css file? (if any)

**clue:** i don't have the jobeet project on the web root folder in the server (/var/www/), i have it in a subdirectory in that directory (/var/www/folder/jobeet/). Can this thing be the cause of the problem? (maybe some autogenerated configuration files have absolute routes)

**clue_2:** looking at the html code i can see the references to the stylesheet files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"    href="/folder/jobeet/web/sfPropelPlugin/css/global.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"     href="/folder/jobeet/web/sfPropelPlugin/css/default.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/folder/jobeet/web/css/main.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/folder/jobeet/web/css/admin.css" />
```

### Edit:

in the backend's job and category modules, the only files are generator.yml. In the job file, for example, i can find this:

```
generator:
  class: sfPropelGenerator
  param:
  model_class:           JobeetJob
  theme:                 admin
  non_verbose_templates: true
  with_show:             false
  singular:              JobeetJob
  plural:                JobeetJobs
  route_prefix:          jobeet_job
  with_propel_route:     1
  actions_base_class:    sfActions

config:
  actions: ~
  fields:
    is_activated: { label: Activated?, help: Whether the user has activated the job, or not }
    is_public:    { label: Public?, help: Whether the job can also be published on affiliate websites, or not }
  list:
    title:  Job Management
    layout:  stacked
    display: [company, position, location, url, is_activated, email]
    #params:  |
    #  %%is_activated%% <small>%%category_id%%</small> - %%company%%
    # (<em>%%email%%</em>) is looking for a %%=position%% (%%location%%)
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:
    title:  Editing job "%%company%%" is looking for a "%%position%%"
  new:
    title:  Job Creation
```

When i uncomment the param lines i have a 500 server internal error message. Is really frustrating when its a copy+paste from the tutorial web.

### Solved:

For some strange reason, removing the multiline mode fo the params: definition (in generator.yml) the stylesheet loads correctly. I dont have idea why is that :S

```
`params:  %%is_activated%% <small>%%category_id%%</small> - %%company%% (<em>%%email%%</em>) is looking for a %%=position%% (%%location%%)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have use this command ?

```
symfony plugin:publish-assets
```

This must "create" sfPropelPlugin directory in your web directory...

Comment: i used the command, but sfPropelPlugin directory contains only images

Comment: This is not the regular behavior of this command. therfore, you can manually make a symbolic link in your web folder to the right sfPropelPlugin web directory, or doing copy/paste. good luck.

Comment: OK, adding manually the /css folder to the created directory loads some css. But i think its not the correct way to do it. Can you tell me how to create a symbolic link manually? If i do the copy/paste, what files i have to copy? all the sfPropelPlugin folder in the /lib directroy?? thank  you

Comment: I recommand you to add an alias in your vhost configuration like indicate in documention : http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration

Comment: this is to have the correct route to the symfony libray, right? i have the libray in the lib directory of the project, because its more portable this way